# Uploading multiple pages in GAE

Tags: html, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm attempting to upload 2 html files to GAE with one of the files containing a link to the other.  I'm pretty sure that I need to upload the html file's associated yaml files for it to properly deploy.

I'm using this command:

`gcloud app deploy --project myprojectname app.yaml index.yaml testPage.yaml`

I then get the following error...

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\CCD Student App\testPage.yaml]
>   Unexpected attribute 'indexes' for object of type AppInfoExternal.

I do not see anything wrong with my yaml for the testPage... does anyone know what exactly I'm doing wrong? This is whats in my testPage.yaml:

```
indexes:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `testPage.yaml` content appears to be a datastore index configuration file, not a service configuration file.

If indeed you want that to be your index configuration file you need to keep its name as indicated in the documentation - [`index.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/indexref). But apparently you already have one such file.

Because of the non-standard name `gcloud app deploy` considers it to be a service/module configuration file and complains because it doesn't find the expected content of such file - [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)

Comment: Oh okay, so how exactly should I code the 'testPage.yaml' for it to be working properly? Whenever I click the link on the page it just says the server cannot find it, which is because the 'testPage.yaml' cannot be deployed (I'm assuming)

Comment: I think you don't have the proper understanding of how GAE apps work, you probably need to do some reading. StackOverflow is not a coding service, you need to show your work and ask coding questions about the specific problems you encounter: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking